# What is best way to store passwords for shell script?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, passwords, backup

I have shell script (example.sh) in Ubuntu 16.04, what I will excecute with cronjob daily to backup databases and archive it in 7z arhive with password.
So I need somehow pass passwords to this script.

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh

mysql_user="root"
mysql_pass="example"
zip_pass="example2"

#there goes logic for backup
...
```

## Issues

- As far as I know, just store passwords in shell script is not correct and unsecure.
- I tried to pass this as arguments to shell script, for example `sh example.sh myStrongMySQLPassword 7zPassword`, but thoose all users can see just using command `ps -ef` in terminal.

So, what is the most secure and best option to run shell scripts with passwords?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a separate `config` file and store credentials in this. Read this config file in your shell script to fetch the credentials.

There are some very good articles on how to do this on `unix stack exchange`. Refer to it for detailed info:

[hiding-password-in-shell-scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212329/hiding-password-in-shell-scripts)